# should scratches on a new bumper be painted over?

Tags: maintenance, paint, paint-scratches

I bought a 2013 car last year and got a small scratch on the bumper. I think someone may have hit it ever so slightly when trying to back in or something I'm not sure.

Anyway, personally, I'm indifferent about it. I don't think it looks that bad from a cosmetic perspective but it was suggested to me that I should get it painted, regardless, because if I don't it could rust.

What do ya'll think?

Comment: What make/model of this vehicle?

Comment: It's a Honda Accord.

Comment: Doesn't the 2013 Accord have soft bumpers, made of urethane type material? If so, no worries of rust.

Comment: You could do it yourself if you're feeling brave. Though car bumpers are usually some type of plastic, so I wouldn't worry about rust.

Comment: Try to cut and polish it first. I have seen 'magic' happen where a machine buffer will just disappear all the scratches on a panel. Pretty cool to watch when it happens.

Answer (score 6):

If this bumper isn't made of metal, then it won't rust. You can try some paint repair magic kit.

If there's a scratch, than you won't be able to get a brand new looking, smooth surface by just painting over. You should repair the scratch properly: sand it, prime it, repaint all or blend in and apply lack, polish.

Answer (score 5):

A photograph of the scratches would help immensely here are light scratches and damage in the paint can be removed with just abrasives such as T-Cut or Rubbing Compound.

The bumper will only rust if it's metal and most modern cars use plastic bumpers.

If you were to get the panel professionally painted, the painter would not simply paint over the scratches but they'd rub the existing paint down to a smooth finish, otherwise you'd see the damage through the new paint.

Answer (score 1):

If your bumper is made out of plastic, i advise not to paint over it. Painting over the scratch will just highlight the scratch. Paint applied on spray painted surfaces dont add up to an even layer and it looks ugly ! You can try buffing off the scratch with some cutting compound and water. If the scratch has only affected the top clear coat, you can remove it by spraying with loads of water and sanding with 2200 grit emery  paper . (Always spray loads of water while sanding or buffing , if you dont the paint gets hot and the surface gets destroyed )